# SQL results to array without duplicated id and post_title in one array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database, join

I am working on received data from the database. I want this data in an array but the ID and post_title returns more than one in the results.

```
wp_posts
+----+------------+
| ID | post_title |
| 1  | radio      |
| 2  | television |
+----+------------+

wp_postmeta
+---------+---------+----------+------------+ 
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
|    1    |    1    | price    | 12.50      |
|    2    |    1    | _sku     | 5876gh7    |
|    3    |    1    | thumb_id | 56         |
|    4    |    2    | price    | 342.50     |
|    5    |    2    | _sku     | tv784      |
|    6    |    2    | thumb_id | 78         |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+ 

$query = "
    SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, m.meta_id, m.meta_key, m.meta_value
    FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (m.post_id = p.ID)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%rad%' AND ID = p.ID)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%rad%' AND post_id = p.ID)
    ORDER BY p.ID, m.meta_id
";


$result     = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = $result->fetch_object() ){
        $sendback[] = $row;
}

print_r($sendback);
```

This is the result that I see if I print this.
You can see the ID and post_title is showing in every result.

```
array(
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [ID]            => 1 
        [post_title]    => Radio  
        [meta_key]      => price 
        [meta_value]    => 12.50 
    ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [ID]            => 1 
        [post_title]    => Radio  
        [meta_key]      => _sku 
        [meta_value]    => 5876gh7
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [ID]            => 1 
        [post_title]    => Radio  
        [meta_key]      => thumb_id 
        [meta_value]    => 56
    )
)
```

Which method can I use to get the ID and post_title once like this

```
array(
        'id'            => '1',
        'post_title'    => 'radio',
        'price'         => '12.50',
        'sku'           => '5876gh7',
        'thumb_id'      => '56'
    )
```

Comment: Before your `ORDER BY`, can you try to add `GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title`?  If this works, I can expand it out into a fuller answer.

Comment: Hi HoldOffHunger I tried this but than I got the ID and post_title once. But also only the first record from wp_postmeta. Like this **1   - radio - price - 12.50**

Comment: Hi, Liekeee: Thanks for getting back to me!  I guess I'm not understanding.  Your question is "Which method can I use to get the ID and post_title once?"  But now your problem with solution is "but than I got the ID and post_title once."  I don't understand?

Comment: I changed my question a little. I add some extra details

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to solve this directly using only SQL, you'll need to process those entries. The reason is that wp_postmeta has many entries for a single wp_posts entry. So what you can do is:

```php
$SQL = <<<SQL
  SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts
SQL;

$posts = $dbh->query($SQL)->fetchAll();
```

You'll have all of your posts

```php
foreach($posts as $post) {
  $prodArr[]['id'] = $post['id'];
  $prodArr[count($prodArr) - 1]['post_title'] = $post['post_title'];
  $SQL = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE post_id = {$post['id']}
SQL;
  $metas = $dbh->query($SQL)->fetchAll();
  foreach($metas as $meta) {
    if ($meta['meta_key'] == 'price')
      $prodArr[count($prodArr) - 1]['price'] = $meta['meta_key'];
    else if ($meta['meta_key'] == '_sku')
      $prodArr[count($prodArr) - 1]['sku'] = $meta['meta_key'];
    else if ($meta['meta_key'] == 'thumb_id')
      $prodArr[count($prodArr) - 1]]['thumb_id'] = $meta['meta_key'];
  }
}
```

So the $prodArr will have all the info you need for all products and then you can iterate it. The code may contain errors, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the list of meta keys that you want to return, you can use conditional aggregation to pivot your dataset and produce the results that you expect:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID, 
    p.post_title, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'price'    THEN m.meta_value END) price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_sku'     THEN m.meta_value END) sku,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'thumb_id' THEN m.meta_value END) thumb_id
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.ID
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%rad%' AND ID = p.ID)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%rad%' AND post_id = p.ID)
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title
ORDER BY p.ID
```

I also suspect that the subqueries in the `WHERE` clause can be simplified:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID, 
    p.post_title, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'price'    THEN m.meta_value END) price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_sku'     THEN m.meta_value END) sku,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'thumb_id' THEN m.meta_value END) thumb_id
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title
HAVING 
    p. post_title LIKE '%rad%'
    OR MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_sku' AND m.meta_value LIKE '%rad%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
ORDER BY p.ID
```

Comment: Don't know why the case statement didn't come to my mind while answering. But i couldn't understand why you used MAX.

Comment: @LeandroJacques: that's the point of conditional aggregation. We need an aggregate function to collapse these rows. It could be `MAX()` or as well `MIN()`, it doesn't really matter.